# Unmatching parentheses in awk command inside bash script causing syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk

This is the error I get after compiling and running the file

```
./skript05.sh: 13: ./skript05.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Here's the important snippet of the code, with line 13 pointed out. I don't think the rest of the code is needed since it works well, but if it is, let me know.

```
ls -l $1 | awk "
    if($1 ~ /-([r-][w-][x-]){3}/) 
    {
        MUCHLINES=$(system(\"egrep -o \"^[a-z ]{1,}$\" \", $9) | wc -l) ;#13
        test -z "$MUCHLINES" && continue ;
        print $9":"$MUCHLINES ;
        >&2 echo "$9":"yes" ;
    }
    else >&2 echo "$9":"no" ;
"
```

What I can figure out is that it ignores symbols {} in lines 12 and 17, but I can't figure out why. All other parentheses are not ignored and highlighted properly when editing code in gedit for example.

I'm working on this in Linux.

I've been searching for answers on this for days, but can't seem to find any. If there are any, I'll apologize and delete this question. Thank you for any help!

(In case you need to know what is this code supposed to do — it should print into stdout "(nameoffile):(x)", where x is number of lines made up of only lowercase letters and spaces; and print into stderr "(nameoffile):yes/no" with yes in case of files (in `ls -l` known by having `-` as first symbol in access rights).)

Comment: Don't it need some spaces around braces?

Comment: Use single quotes around the script as a whole; then you don't have to escape double quotes etc inside the script.

Comment: Having said that (I think it's accurate advice), I can't work out what parts of the script shown are Awk and which are shell.  I'd proffer an answer if I was able to work out what you're up to.  The whole `if` needs to be inside `{ … }` so it matches each line of input to Awk.

Comment: Your script is a mush of awk and shell syntax. awk is not shell, just like C and Java are not shell. Get the books Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson but meantime if you post some sample input and expected output someone can help you AFTER we tell you not to try to parse the output of `ls` (google it). And what do you mean by `after compiling...`? shell and awk are different languages but one thing they have in common is they're interpreted, not compiled!

Comment: Also, be aware that parsing `ls` output is error prone.  On Mac, for example (but also Linux), you can have an extra character such as `@` after the basic permissions, so your regex wouldn't match all files on Mac.  And you have problems with spaces (etc) in file names.  Use single quotes around the script as a whole; then you don't have to escape double quotes etc inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

@EdW - As others have pointed out, the script that you posted is a jumble, but I thought that the following might be helpful to you in that it does illustrate how one can combine ls, awk, and egrep in a bash script, more or less along the lines you seem to have had in mind.  Please note, however, that it does NOT address some of the issues that others have raised, nor is it intended to serve as a model.  It probably does not even do precisely what you want, but I hope you find it helpful in achieving some of your goals.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ls -l $1 | awk '{print $1, $9}' | while read mask file
    do
    if [[ $mask =~ -([r-][w-][x-]){3} ]] ; then
        MUCHLINES=$(egrep -o "^[a-z ]{1,}$" "$file" | wc -l)
        if [[ $MUCHLINES -gt 0 ]] ; then
          echo "$file:" $MUCHLINES
          >&2 echo "$file:yes"
        else
          >&2 echo "$file:no"
        fi
    fi
    done
```

Comment: @EdW: Thanks.  Did you know that you can increase your stackoverflow "reputation" by marking an answer as accepted? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers